# How to make a download file in JSF 2.0?

Tags: jsf-2

I have file locate inside `WebContent/WEB-INF/resources/file/theFile.pdf`, may I know how can I download the file that will show a regular download popup dialog or render it in the webpage (either one will do as long as the simplest way to go) when user click on the link of a page? I am using JSF2.0, and currently using `h:outputLink` to download the pdf file but no luck, the console output show me this error:

```
File not found: /pages/resources/file/theFile.pdf
```

How can tell JSF to remove the `/pages` and begin with the `/resources` as my file was sit inside resources folder.

This is the download code:

```
<h:outputLink value="resources/file/theFile.pdf">
  <h:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.jpg" style="border:none"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *I have file locate inside `WebContent/WEB-INF/resources/file/theFile.pdf`*

First of all, the content of `/WEB-INF` (and `/META-INF`) is **not** publicly available (as they may contain sensitive information such as `web.xml`, tag files, templates, etc). Put the file in public webcontent *outside* `/WEB-INF`.

Assuming that it's now located in `WebContent/resources/file/theFile.pdf`, then you can link to it as follows:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/file/theFile.pdf">
    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.jpg" style="border:none"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your usage of `library` attribute on `<h:graphicImage>` makes no sense. See also [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 3):

Try with `#{request.contextPath}` prefix

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/file/theFile.pdf">
    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.jpg" style="border:none"/>
</h:outputLink>
```